# How to low the instantiate frequency in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to low the shot frequency like this:

```
public class createShot : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject shot;

    void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine("Shot");
    }

    IEnumerator Shot()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            Instantiate(shot, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }
    }
}
```

but it keeps spamming a lot shots in less than a second... Can someone help? It's a 2D project in Unity5

Comment: You are starting a new `Coroutine` every single frame - that's definitely not what you should be doing. Most likely you want your coroutine to set a boolean value (`isOnCooldown` or something along those lines) and only start that coroutine *after* you shot

Comment: Yeah, I want something like a cooldown, but I started yesterday on Unity, haha. How can I set this cooldown correctly? The way I did I thought that the WaitForSeconds would "stop" the each frame update

Comment: As I already said, have a boolean, which when set to `true` prevents the instantiation of `shot` and have your coroutine set that to `false` after the cooldown ends

Comment: You shouldn't name your class `createShot`. That sounds more like a method name. You should name your classes nouns. `ShotCreator` would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want something more like this:

```
float elapsedTime;
[SerializeField]
float targetTime = 1f;

void Update() 
{
    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

    if(elapsedTime >= targetTime && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        elapsedTime = 0;
        Instantiate(shot, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

This would increase a timer `elapsedTime` and check wether it exceeds the `targetTime`.

I also would encourage you to stop using strings whenever possible. Do not use them when calling methods nor when requesting something like the key in GetKey. They create garbage and slow your software.

Comment: Exactly what I need! I just reduced a bit the targetTime e works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: You can also add a [SerializeField]-attribute above `targetTime` and then you can set it in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternatively...

Using the exact same code already written, we can make some slight adjustments and get things working just fine.

```
public class createShot : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject shot;

    void Start() //create the coroutine once
    {
        StartCoroutine("Shot");
    }

    IEnumerator Shot()
    {
        while(true) { //do this forever!
        //This is what makes it loop and what allows the WaitForSeconds() do its job
            if (Input.GetKey("space"))
            {
                Instantiate(shot, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            }
            else {
                yield return null; //wait 1 frame instead
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside, you should always name your classes with a Leading Capital Letter, e.g. `CreateShot` instead of `createShot`.

Comment: So, basically, WaitForSeconds only works if inside a loop?

Comment: @IgorHenriques No, what it does it cause the function to pause execution for a duration (the `yield` is responsible for the pause, what you return when yielding determines the duration: null is next frame, other objects are "evaluated" every frame until they "return true", see [WaitUntil](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html)). As your original code *had no lines* after the `yield` there was nothing left to execute. In my code, there is: the `while` loop.

Comment: if you had `IEnumerator Shot() { yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); Debug.Log("Shot!"); }` instead, you'd find that the log statement would come one second after `Shot()` gets called, even though there is no loop.

Comment: You can *kind of* think of Coroutines like threads, where `StartCoroutine()`  creates a subtask and all `yields` act like `Thread.sleep()`, but that everything is still synchronous and running on the main thread. There's still the usual dangers of "be careful what you modify" but you can't cause *true* race conditions where two different sections of code access the same object at the same CPU cycle.